# Handle sass with meteor

Tags: meteor, sass

Is there an easy way to integrate sass with [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). If I do

```
$> meteor list
```

sass is not there. Is it possible or do I have to do sass outside of meteor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the third party package repositor [Atmoshpere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) to use packages that are not built into core Meteor.

One package that you may want to look at is probably: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/scss which is basically Node-sass wrapped to work with meteor.

To be able to use packages from Atmosphere, you need to have [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) installed which you can do by

```
$ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

and then using meteorite, you can install that package running

```
$ mrt add scss
```

Note that you now use `mrt` istead of `meteor` but there is great news that meteorite and atmosphere is going to be rolled into core Meteor, becoming the official repo.

There is also a beta version of Atmoshpere v2 where you can browse packages more intuitively at: http://beta.atmospherejs.com/

Comment: `mrt`, I've seen it before! All the pieces are coming together :)

Comment: `mrt` is the command replacement for `meteor` that comes from the meteorite npm package, which works against the atmosphere package repository. You'll want to use it. always! :)

Comment: Hopefully soon we'll have `mrt` folded into meteor so that this confusion will no longer be an issue! That is discussed in the meteor blog [here](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/02/20/the-new-atmosphere-beta-is-out)

Comment: I'm used to run the development environment using grunt, so it can watch files and perform actions. For example, what about the grunt task **autoprefixer**, can I run something like that using `mrt` ?

Comment: grunt is not a meteor workflow tool, meteor does the conversion at deploy/run time and does not create visible compiled files for you, instead it creates a bundle which you don't normally look at. But for grunt, there is talks of a new third party atmosphere package that is currently being developed, but it is not out yet

Answer (score 2):

found this question today.  its been a over a year and things have changed a lot.

`meteor add fourseven:scss` and `meteor add francocatena:compass` are currently leading the way for sass support in meteor.  thanks to this question tonight, i'm going to install them and start using them tonight.  enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a package being worked on [here](https://github.com/particle4dev/meteor-sass) though I'm not sure how complete it is, it's worth a try!

Comment: nice, thnx! I'll check it out!